# pageChange doesn't remove old events

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm having alot of problems with jQuery mobile and really want to shoot myself in the head.

I have the a page with this code:

```
$(document).on('pageinit ',function(){
$("#phone_number").on("blur", function (event, ui) {


    $.mobile.changePage("<?php echo base_url(); ?>mobile/products_by_phone",  {
     type: "POST",
     data: {phone :  $('#phone_number').val() },
    transition: "flip"} );

});
});
```

Now the page has valid html and markup of jQuery mobile which containsthe following code :

```
$(document).on('pageinit ',function(){
 alert();
 });
```

Now when i change page it works, but when i invoke the `blur` event again, the page changes twice, i do it again then 4 times , then 8, etc.

**And** pressing the browsers back button works, but when i try and press forward nothing happens.

**Notes:**

- I've thought maybe it's related to the blur and each time changePage happens blur fires so i tried adding a button and binding to a click but same thing happpend
- I've thought maybe the fact that i bind to `document` causes it, so i tried binding to the page id but that didn't work at all(nothing happens as no events were binded), then i tried triggering a create event but that also didn't bind the events

Why does this happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add the page you want to bind the init event to... Assuming you want this bound once, which you do, you just need to be more specific.

Example:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page1', function(e){...});
```

Replace the #page1 with your page ID.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with jQuery mobile, but I assume the `changePage()` function loads the new page content using an AJAX call. If that is the case, then the existing event handlers are going to remain, and you'll simply be adding more of them every time.

Try using the [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) function to remove the event handler before (re-)binding it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common jQuery mobile problem. It is caused because multiple events are bind to same element. Every time you return to previous page you bind same event again.

There are 2 solutions for this problem.

Before you bind an event to some element check if that same event is not already bind.

**Example:**

```
$('.menu-browse:Event(!' + touchEvent + ')').each(function(){
    $('.menu-browse').bind(touchEvent, function(e) {

    });
});
```

Here you will find a full implementation of Event filter: http://www.codenothing.com/archives/2009/event-filter/

Or:

Each time you bind an event, unbind it before.

**Example:**

```
$(document).unbind();
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(e) {

});
```

or:

```
$(document).die();
$(document).live('pageinit', function(e) {

});
```

or in your case:

```
$(document).off(); 
$(document).on('pageinit',function(){
    alert();
});
```

Sadly there are none bulletproof solutions for this problem.

Comment: Well the first is giving me `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: Event ` and off and die both don't work, same is happening and this still doesn't answer why the forward button doesn't work. if it matters in the new page my events don't get binded too...